# display a map with FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have this map:

```
{
  "2" : {
    "name" : "JOHN"
  },
  "1" : {
    "name" : "JENNY" 
  }
}
```

How to display this map using FreeMarker? I tried this line:

```
<#list map?keys as key>${map[key].name}</#list>
```

But it says that `Expression map is undefined`...

Comment: With what name have you put that map into the data-model?

Comment: No name. I added it and it worked. Thanks!